# Conflict between jquery "position().top" and css3 "transform: scale()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I'm building a font resizer in my editing tool, for this tool I changed the origin of my text elements to be on the bottom left. Everything works on the normal version but I'm trying to make it work with my zoom feature that uses `transform:scale(...)` :

So here's the normal version, see that the text always sticks to line whatever is the font-size :

```js
$(document).on('change', '#fontsize', function() {
  var element = $(".element");
  var fontsize = $(this).val();
  var current_top = element.position().top;
  var height = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
  var bottom = current_top + height;

  console.log('font-size=' + fontsize + ' top=' + current_top + ' height=' + height);

  element.css({
    "font-size": fontsize + 'px',
  }).css({
    top: (current_top - ((current_top + element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height) - bottom)) + 'px'
  })

});
```

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.elements {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 70px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fontsize" type="text" placeholder="Type : '21', '23' or '28'">
<span>Press enter !</span>

<div class="elements">
  <span class="absolute" style="top: 65px; z-index:999;"></span>
  <div class="element" style="">Lindow</div>
</div>
```

And Here's the version that uses `transform:scale(...)`, as you can see here `element.position().top` does some weird things, the text doesn't stay on top of the line and moves elsewhere on each input change.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#fontsize', function() {
  var element = $(".element");
  var fontsize = $(this).val();
  var current_top = element.position().top;
  var height = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
  var bottom = current_top + height;

  console.log('font-size=' + fontsize + ' top=' + current_top + ' height=' + height);

  element.css({
    "font-size": fontsize + 'px',
  }).css({
    top: (current_top - ((current_top + element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height) - bottom)) + 'px'
  })

});
```

```css
.elements {
  transform:scale(1.5); 
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.elements {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 70px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fontsize" type="text" placeholder="Type : '21', '23' or '28'">
<span>Press enter !</span>

<div class="elements">
  <span class="absolute" style="top: 65px; z-index:999;"></span>
  <div class="element" style="">Lindow</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to resolve this issue, what's going wrong and what should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are changing an element's font size it increase's its height, and with absolute positioning, you are better of working from its `bottom` position, not `top`.

I simplified the script and changed to `bottom: 72px` in the `.element` rule.

*Note, the gap between the bottom of the text and the green line belong to the font and increase with the font size. This is normal and is based on the font's internal metrics, which also can/will differ between font types. If you need to compensate for that as well, you need to measure the used font's values and add it to your calculations (and be aware, this might also differ between browsers and operating systems).*

---

Non-scaled version

```js
$(document).on('change', '#fontsize', function() {
  var element = $(".element");
  var fontsize = $(this).val();
  
  console.log('font-size=' + fontsize);

  element.css({
    "font-size": fontsize + 'px',
  })

});
```

```css
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.elements {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fontsize" type="text" placeholder="Type : '21', '23' or '28'">
<span>Press enter !</span>

<div class="elements">
  <span class="absolute" style="top: 65px; z-index:999;"></span>
  <div class="element" style="">Lindow</div>
</div>
```

---

Scaled version

```js
$(document).on('change', '#fontsize', function() {
  var element = $(".element");
  var fontsize = $(this).val();
  
  console.log('font-size=' + fontsize);

  element.css({
    "font-size": fontsize + 'px',
  })

});
```

```css
.elements {
  transform:scale(1.5); 
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.elements {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 70px;
  bottom: 72px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fontsize" type="text" placeholder="Type : '21', '23' or '28'">
<span>Press enter !</span>

<div class="elements">
  <span class="absolute" style="top: 65px; z-index:999;"></span>
  <div class="element" style="">Lindow</div>
</div>
```

---

**Updated**

If you still want to base it on its `top` value, you need to get the `scale()` value and then use the difference between the old and new `height` to adjust the `top` value

```js
$(document).on('change', '#fontsize', function() {
  var element = $(".element");
  var scale = (element[0].getBoundingClientRect().width / element[0].offsetWidth);  
  var fontsize = $(this).val();
  var top = element.position().top / scale;
  var height = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height / scale;

  element.css({
    "font-size": fontsize + 'px',
  }).css({
    top: top - ((element[0].getBoundingClientRect().height / scale) - height) + 'px'
  })

});
```

```css
.elements {
  transform:scale(1.5); 
  transform-origin:top left;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.elements {
  background: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  left: 70px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fontsize" type="text" placeholder="Type : '21', '23' or '28'">
<span>Press enter !</span>

<div class="elements">
  <span class="absolute" style="top: 65px; z-index:999;"></span>
  <div class="element" style="">Lindow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess using calculations is too soon yet since I don't want to struggle with cross-browser compatibility. I'll use bottom value

Comment: @Lindow I updated with a version to keep up with your need to enable _dragging_.